# ntheorem and mathdesign are incompatible

Tags: fonts, theorems, mathdesign, incompatibility

I want to use mathdesign fonts (namely bitstream-charter) and I also want to use the ntheorem package. However, it looks like ntheorem tries to load `amssymb` which is incompatible with mathdesign (it redefines all the relevant symbols itself). How can I fix this?

Here is *a* MWE, although the order doesn't matter, it breaks both ways round. It also breaks with the `thmmarks` option instead of `amsmath` option

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[amsmath]{ntheorem}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\begin{document}
Foo
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps a matter of the load sequence. A minimal example might be helpful.

Comment: No, `ntheorem` doesn't try to load `amssymb` at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath]{ntheorem}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\begin{document}
Foo
\end{document}
```

I think.

Comment: Now, why does this work, when the error I was getting before was the mathdesign warning that it was incompatible with amssymb?

Comment: `ntheorem` is really compatible with `amssymb`, while `mathdesign` isn't. The `[amsmath]` option makes `ntheorem` to be compatiible with `amsmath`, but does not load `amsmath` --- this is the problem here.

Comment: I'm still getting these errors in my main document: Package mathdesign/mdbch Warning: Package 'amssymb' shouldn't be used in conjonction with package mdbch, on input line 138.


Package mathdesign/mdbch Warning: Package 'amsfonts' shouldn't be used in conjonction with package mdbch, on input line 138.

Comment: The test code in answer works fine for me. Maybe you should check your other code or update the latest packages.

Comment: An additional explanation: Do *not* use `amssymb` or `amsfonts` in your document, if you have already use `mathdesign`. Maybe `ntheorem` does not concern the problem here.

Comment: I don't have `amssymb` or `amsmath` anywhere in my preamble. (I even deleted the commented out declarations) But I still get these warnings. The document compiles fine with things in this order, but the warnings are still there. They refer to the input line of the `\begin{document}`

Answer (score 3):

Saying `\expandafter\def\csname ver@amssymb.sty\endcsname{9999/12/31 prevent loading}` should trick LaTeX into believing there's an infinitely new version of amssymb already loaded, hence preventing any \usepackage{amssymb} from having any effect (beyond possibly parameter clashes).